# Group by on a value from different table

Tags: sql, db2, aggregate-functions

I have two tables.

- First table have columns: price, code_one
- Second table has: code_one, code_two

Both tables could be joined using `code_one` table.

How to have "Sum of prices grouped by code_two" ?

I tried:

```
Select sum(price) from table1 Group By (select a.code_two from table2 a, table1 b where a.code_one = b.code_one)
```

Comment: @OMG Ponies: I tried having a sub query after Group By... Something like: Group By (Select a.code_two from table2 a, table1 b where b.code_one = a.code_two)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select code_two, SUM(price)
from table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.code_one = t2.code_one
group by code_two
```

Comment: What if there is a where condition in table1. Like say a date field. So I want only for a particular date. Is the following correct: select code_two, SUM(price) from table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.code_one = t2.code_one where t1.date = 'somedate' group by code_two ???

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(price) 'Price' from firsttable inner join secondtable on firsttable.code_one = secondtable.code_one
group by secondtable.code_two
```